# Delete rows which have common zeros in a datasets using matlab?

Tags: matlab, dataset

I have a datasets in a matlab which have three rows. Now want to delete rows where all three columns are 0, I have written a code below :

```
data = my matlab datasets;
data( ~any(data,2), : ) = [];
```

After running this I am getting following error :

> Undefined function 'any' for input arguments of type 'dataset'

Can you help me where I making mistake ??
Thanks in advance

This is the following datasets :

```
0    7.0103     2.999808

0    7.384439   2.953712

0    6.80119    2.897427

0      0            0

0      0            0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3kn9.jpg)

Comment: Mybe your `dataset` is an object of a class different than Matlab matrix type?

Comment: The issue seems to be because you are using a `dataset` type instead of a regular matrix of doubles. You need to post the actual MATLAB syntax for creating your dataset, not just some numbers. Also, I'm assuming you mean you want to delete rows where all three *columns* are `0`?

Comment: I have data in a big access file which i converted into  a datasets using sql and from that datasets I want to delete rows where all there columns are zero..... I updated a screenshot of my data sets please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'dataset' seems to be an old version of table. You should consider changing the type permanently as 'table' offers what you need and 'dataset' does not.

```
%transform to table
data2=dataset2table(data);
%your command
data2( ~any(data2,2), : ) = [];
%tranform it back to dataset if you want to but i wouldnt recommend
data=table2dataset(data2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I also solved this problem and I have different approach. See my codes below :    ds=struct2dataset(March_2009);
test = double(ds(:,4:6));
test( ~any(test,2), : ) = [];    % Delete rows where all three columns are 0,           
               I am getting what U supposed to get.. Is this one correct..??

Comment: if you get the right result both approaches are fine, the difference is just that i went for 'dataset2table' and you for 'double'. As mentioned i think 'dataset is a little outdated so i would reccomend you to go for 'table', or as you did it make a matrix out of it via 'double()'